# Is it bad/dangerous/damaging to set laptop fan speed to max all the time?

Tags: laptop, cpu, gpu, fan

I use [HWiNFO](http://www.hwinfo.com/) to set my fan speed to maximum (the maximum provided in HWiNFO, there may be higher speeds) all the time I am using my laptop to cool the processor and GPU while video editing and playing games but also when doing normal tasks. Basically, all the time the laptop is on.

Is this damaging to the processor or the GPU or the fan itself? Does it shorten its life for example?

Comment: You could possibly damage the fan - and not he CPU or GPU

Answer (score 3):

You might wear the fan out faster, but by keeping your CPU and GPU at a lower operating temperature, they will have longer life expectancies.

Overall the main downside of having the fan running at full speed the whole time is the noise pollution. If that doesn't bother you, go ahead.

Alternatively, you can buy certain laptop 'stands' that have fans built in.